# Bring about Photoshop-like Bevel effect using svg/Raphaeljs

Tags: svg, raphael

Is there any way to bring about the bevel effect like the one in photoshop in svg or by using an external js like Raphaeljs.? I tried in raphael but it doesnt look that good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are so many "Photoshop bevel effects", so my advice would be to pull up Inkscape, create the bevel effect you want, then look the resulting SVG code and pick what you like.